# Code First Migration Change Attribute ForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, code-first

Bascially I want to update this Class something like this

```
 [ForeignKey("User")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthRole")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string AuthRoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual AuthRole AuthRole { get; set; }
```

to

```
 [ForeignKey("User")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthRole")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string AuthRoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthRoleId")]
    public virtual AuthRole AuthRole { get; set; }
```

I use code first for this, I wonder, do I need migration for just update attribute 
  [ForeignKey("UserId")] to  [ForeignKey("AuthRoleId")]?

or just change the class model?

Thank you

Comment: As an FYI: you don't need any of those `[ForeignKey]`, at all, since you are using *Convention over Configuration* correctly

Comment: Depends on whether you have existing data. FK changes can get messy. As Camilo said, you don't technically need any FK annotations, but if you do want them for clarity, just add them to either the FK or the nav - not both.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thank you  so if I change ForeignKey there is no worry about messy migration right?

Comment: @SteveGreene yes there is no exisitng data, but i just want to make sure if I change this attribute my migration don't get messy.

Comment: I avoid migrations like the plague. You don't ever need migrations. Just check on the database whether the FK generated on `AuthRoleId` points to `AuthRole` or to `User` (it will likely be correctly pointing to `AuthRole`)

Comment: yeah correctly like this   `this.AddColumn("dbo.AuthUserRole", "UserId", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));` and 
            `this.AddColumn("dbo.AuthUserRole", "AuthRoleId", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));`  actually I just follow this legacy code, just worry about the effect that may cause, thank you for your answer @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: There is nothing wrong with migrations when used correctly. We never use them for PROD (we generate a script for DBA), but in DEV/UAT they come in pretty handy for a constantly evolving model.

Comment: what if I want to remove other attribute such as [MaxLength(10)] attribute in some ForeignKey attribute, but when I generate migration, the db correctly generate length related to Parent Table, is it make my code get messy or not? thank you